# What's the best way to mix Ruby and other languages? (Especially C++)

Tags: c++, ruby, interop

I'm learning Ruby, and I'm starting to play with building extensions in C. I have *Programming Ruby The Pragmatic Programmers' Guide* and so I can follow that for the basic nuts and bolts. What I was wondering is if there already existed some nifty frameworks/whatever to help interoperability between Ruby and other languages, with C++ being the most important for me. I've tried googling, but the results focus on language comparisons, rather than language interoperability.

TIA,

Andy

Comment: There is cplus2ruby (http://rubyforge.org/projects/cplus2ruby/) although I cannot comment in-depth on its usefullness, I'll leave that to the ruby experts...

Comment: Very interesting, I'll definitely have to play with that a bit, thanks! (SWIG has the advantage of playing with many different scripting languages... ooh, decisions, decisions!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/). It's a nice framework for integrating C and C++ programs with other programs written in higher level languages. It was originally written to support Python, TCL, and Perl, but has been expanded to support Ruby as well.

Comment: PS can't vote your answer up. I find this whole reputation thing really funny - it's like an RPG and XP! Now when do I get magic missiles?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Ruby with Java, then look into JRuby. It is a Java implementation of Ruby and allows you to call Java libraries/code through Ruby.

http://jruby.org/

Comment: Thanks. I've heard of it, but not looked into it. I imagine I might want to use it for running my Ruby code (need to investigate pros v cons), but I don't think I'd want to do my extensions in Java. It's mainly for performance reasons that I'll be making other language extensions, and I'm most comfortable with C++ anyway...

Answer (score 0):

FFI is the recommended way to hook Ruby implementations up to C libraries, but a bit of Googling suggests that this probably won't work as-is with C++, so try SWIG. There's an FFI-SWIG thing [here](http://github.com/sunaku/swig-ruby-ffi).

Comment: Thanks, interesting. From a quick glance it seems that its big advantage would be that I could make C libraries that are not tied to Ruby in any way (no ruby.h, no rb_define_class, etc.) and interface with them using this. Nice, but not exactly what I was looking for in this case. Thanks again.